# Simple hardware tests to eliminate a PC as causing wifi dropouts

Tags: wireless-networking

How can I test my netbook's wifi receiver/transmitter, to eliminate it as a possibility in some network problems?

I'm attacking the problem from the other end ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/200857/moving-wifi-router-and-possibly-cable-modem-which-cables-should-i-lengthen) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/200388/wifi-interference-and-the-airport-interference-robustness-setting)), and it's looking as if the solution is *probably* to get a wifi extender. (The dropouts go away when I get close to the transmitter -- I think -- and the other wifi user isn't having problems.)

However, I'd hate to drop some money and then find out I hadn't fixed the problem.

Is there a way to run some tests on the hardware, without buying anything (or very much) to completely eliminate the netbook as a culprit?

Specs:

The netbook is an Asus Eee PC running Windows 7 Starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your WiFi channel to 11 (the strongest) and see if that helps.

If it doesn't, as mentioned in your second link, use [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider) to map all signals around you.
The problem can always be your neighbor's router, but also your new microwave or even metallic cupboards positioned between you and your router.

Comment: It's currently set to "automatic", wouldn't that choose the strongest channel?

Comment: I refer to the channel the router is sending on. You have to logon to the router to change this.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the router software for this, and it has an 
"automatic" setting. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/5vcLO.png)

Comment: Turned off interference robustness, switched to channel 11, will see id this works.

Comment: Seeing definite improvement with channel 11 and interference robustness off.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your hardware tests end up at best inconclusive, one option is to try a usb wifi adapter.  They [can be had for < $10](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb+wifi&x=0&y=0).

Comment: Do note that it's entirely likely that whatever you're already using has much better range than any USB wifi dongle. ;) +1